# How to color portion of a slider in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, slider, media

I'm creating a video player and I want to color only a portion (with custom values) in the slider like this:

[image]

how can I do?

I've colored the whole bar up to now, but I can't color just different portions:

```
            StackPane trackPane = (StackPane) seekSlider.lookup(".track");
            trackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e5e5e5");
```

Comment: I would be tempted to make the slider transparent, and then put it in a StackPane with another Pane containing the blue shapes at the bottom.  Set the size of the shape Pane to the same dimensions as the Slider and position the blue shapes in the Pane where you want them.  Probably less fiddly than trying to get linear gradients to work.

Comment: @DaveB how to position the blue shapes in the Pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment on the question, here's some code that will do the trick.  It takes just a little bit of messing about with the styling of the "track" element of the Slider to make it transparent, and then the rest falls in place.

BTW:  This is Kotlin, but you should be able to figure out how it works, if you have any questions, I can update this with some explanations:

```
class FancySlider : Application() {
   override fun start(stage: Stage) {
      stage.scene = Scene(createContent()).apply {
         FancySlider::class.java.getResource("/css/default.css")?.toString()?.let { stylesheets += it }
      }
      stage.show()
   }

   private fun createContent(): Region {
      val stackPane = StackPane().apply {
         val slider = Slider().apply {
            minWidth = 300.0
            styleClass += "fancy-slider"
         }
         val pane = Pane().apply {
            val heightAdjust = 8.0
            val widthAdjust = 10.0
            maxHeightProperty().bind(slider.heightProperty().subtract(heightAdjust))
            minHeightProperty().bind(slider.heightProperty().subtract(heightAdjust))
            maxWidthProperty().bind(slider.widthProperty().subtract(widthAdjust))
            minWidthProperty().bind(slider.widthProperty().subtract(widthAdjust))
            children += createRectangle(this.widthProperty(), 0.43, 0.08)
            children += createRectangle(this.widthProperty(), 0.12, 0.15)
            children += createRectangle(this.widthProperty(), 0.75, 0.03)
         }
         children += listOf(pane, slider)
         minHeight = 60.0
         padding = Insets(20.0)
      }
      return stackPane
   }

   fun createRectangle(sliderWidthProperty: ReadOnlyDoubleProperty, startPos: Double, duration: Double) = Rectangle(1.0, 7.0).apply {
      layoutXProperty().bind(sliderWidthProperty.multiply(startPos))
      widthProperty().bind(sliderWidthProperty.multiply(duration))
      fill = Color.DARKBLUE
      styleClass += "fancy-slider-rectangle"
   }
}

fun main() {
   Application.launch(FancySlider::class.java)
}
```

And the CSS stuff looks like this:

```
.fancy-slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%);
    -fx-background-insets: 2;
    -fx-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.25em
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
}

.fancy-slider-rectangle {
  -fx-arc-width: 6.0;
  -fx-arc-height: 6.0;
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. This is only for horizontal Sliders, you'd have to rework it for a verticle Slider.
2. The width and height bindings for the Pane are set with hard-coded adjustments, and I'm not sure what would happen if you could somehow change the height of the Slider.
3. The StackPane keeps everything lined up nicely, since it centres by default, so long as you get the right height and width for the Pane is should just align nicely.
4. You could implement this as a custom Node and expose an addRectangle() method which worked nicely with the Slider's conversions of it's value.

Anyways, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it thanks to your answer!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Did you have any difficulties with the Kotlin?

Comment: The Kotlin reads a lot like [JavaFX Script](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/getting-started-with-javafx.html#borders) but is backed by a well-supported language.  I don't have a difficulty with it, at least this small snippet anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you play around with linear gradients, I think those can solve you issues:

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 30% 30% to 23% 30%, repeat,  #e9967a 62%, #ff8c00 88%);
```

For more info you can look at the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Okay thank you, do you think I have to iterate through the slider values? Becouse this color have to be applied before the video starts

Answer (score 3):

If you are not very concerned about curved highlights, below is a way you can try with. This is on the same lines what @Nina Koninckx suggested.

The general idea is, we paint the track color using linear gradient color stops.

Lets say the default track color is `white` and you need to highlight the sections(50%-70% and 80%-90%) with `blue`. You define all individual sections with the percentage values. Like

- white 50% (default start with 0% so no need to specify)
- blue 50% , blue 70% ,
- white 70% , white 80% ,
- blue 80% , blue 90% ,
- white 90% , white 100%

Combining all, the linear gradient styling will be like:

```
linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 0% , white 50% , blue 50% , blue 70% , white 70% , white 80% , blue 80% , blue 90% , white 90% , white 100% )
```

Then we create a variable( lets say `-track-color`) for slider in CSS, and we update the variable in the java code.

Below is a quick demo of the example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class SliderStylingDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 30) ;
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(10);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        String style = "-track-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 0% , white 50% , blue 50% , blue 70% , white 70% , white 80% , blue 80% , blue 90% , white 90% , white 100% )";
        slider.setStyle(style);
        VBox root = new VBox(slider);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setSpacing(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 100);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("sliderstyle.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Slider Styling Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.slider {
    -track-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
}
.slider .track {
      -fx-background-color:
          -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          -track-color;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Linear gradients can be defined in code using Java API rather than CSS.  For a static gradient, CSS is probably fine.  But if you wanted to dynamically change the stops to different settings at runtime, it would probably be best to use the Java API.